# How do you find out the type of an object

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How can I know that inputed value is image, string, audio or video in 
   swift if someone have idea please help me.

In sort, I want to know type of the object.

```
 cell = Chat_CollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
   Identifier, for: indexPath)as! SingleChat_Cell 
 let data = sender.object(at: indexPath.row)
```

Now I wanted to know the datatype of the data

Comment: If you're retrieving the data  from a URL, then presumably you can inspect the HTTP response headers. Does the Content-Type header contain anything useful?

Comment: nope  Content-Type didn't contain anything

Comment: you need to show more information for us to help you, we dont know where data is coming from.

Comment: `cell = Chat_CollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:  Identifier, for: indexPath)as! SingleChat_Cell` why you put this code part here?, how it is related to data/sender ?

Comment: So what's its current type? is it `AnyObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cell = Chat_CollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
                    Identifier, for: indexPath)as! SingleChat_Cell 

 let data = sender.object(at: indexPath.row)   
 if  (data as? String) != nil { // check if data is String type
        // your code here
 }

 if  (data as? UIImage) != nil { // check if data is UIImage type
        // your code here

 }

 if  (data as? Data) != nil { // check if data is Data type for audio or video
        // your code here

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

just use

> print(type(of: data))